# serve: command not found React js deloyment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to reinstall the serve using "npm install -g serve" and "npm i -S serve" but the error is still not resolved. kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `npm run serve`?

Comment: yes i didstill the same

Answer (score 1):

You should first install [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package globally on you computer as suggested in the installation output with

```
npm install -g serve
```